# Computing FIRST and FOLLOW sets for top down parsing, for the following grammar

Tags: compiler-construction

For the grammar below, I have computed the FIRST and FOLLOW sets
    S->a|+|(T)
    T->T.S|S
Solution: 
After eliminating the left recursion, the grammar is:

```
S->a|+|(T)
T->aT'|+T'|(T)T'
T'->.ST'|epsilon
```

Now the FIRST sets are: 
    FIRST(S)={a,+,(}
    FIRST(T)={a,+,(}
    FIRST(T')={. , epsilon}

The FOLLOW sets are:
    FOLLOW(S)={. , $}
    FOLLOW(T)={)}
    FOLLOW(T')={)}

Is the non-left recursive grammar and the FOLLOW sets correct? So can someone tell me whether I have arrived at the correct solution. I am confused whether `$` will be added to the FOLLOW set for `T` and `T'` also...
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
First sets, Straight forward:
S  = { a, +, ( }
T  = { a, +, ( }
T' = {epsilon, .}

Follow Sets:
S  = { ), ., $ }
T  = { ) }
T' = { ) }

As per the definition of follow from dragon book:

1. Place $ in FOLLOW(S) , where S is the start symbol, and $ is the input
right end marker .

2. If there is a production A -> aBβ, then everything in FIRST(β) except ε
is in FOLLOW(B) .

3. If there is a production A -> aB, or a production A -> aBβ, where
FIRST(β) contains ε, then everything in FOLLOW(A) is in FOLLOW(B) .

Follow of S contains ')' if we apply the rule 3:
T' -> .ST'

As per rule 3: a = . , B = S , T' = β and FIRST(T') contains 'ε', everything in Follow of T' is in Follow of S. Since follow of T' contains ')' it also becomes member of S.
```